# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') when I try to use the Image component of next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I'm trying to use the Image component provided by `next.js`.

This Is My Simple Header Component

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import React from 'react'
import myImage from '../assets/IMG-20221115-WA0001.jpg'

function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
        <div>
            <div>
                <Image
                    src={myImage}
                    width={50}
                    height={10}
                    alt="Logo"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

The error seems to be [error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35kIS.png) from the webpack, so I don't exactly know how to resolve it.

Comment: Please consider providing error as text, not as image

Answer (score 0):

You can move the image to the `/public` folder and pass the path to the src Image property

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import React from 'react'

function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
        <div>
            <div>
                <Image
                    src={'/IMG-20221115-WA0001.jpg'}
                    width={50}
                    height={10}
                    alt="Logo"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

To make Next/Image work, you need to provide the path see https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#src

note: you can leave the image in the same path and pass it to the `src` property but using the relative path instead of statically imported

Comment: Thanks for answering, but actually when I am using the Image component in a component under the pages folder which renders on client side the solution works well, but when I am using the experimental appDir and using Image inside the Header component which is rendered Server side this error occurs. The Image is rendered but after a second or two it causes the above error I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add require for giving absolute path

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import React from 'react'
import myImage from '../assets/IMG-20221115-WA0001.jpg'

function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
        <div>
            <div>
                <Image
                    src={require(myImage)}
                    width={50}
                    height={10}
                    alt="Logo"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```